# Crash when set value to parent controller in Singleton

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, uiviewcontroller, singleton

[image]

AnspruchstellerVC and VersicherungsnehmerVC inherited from BaseVC.

```
@interface BaseVC : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *tag;

@end
```

Can set value for AnspruchstellerVC but for VersicherungsnehmerVC it isn't work.
[image]

```
- (UIViewController *)loadViewControllerByID:(NSString *)vcID
{
    NSParameterAssert(vcID);

    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:vcID];
    return vc;
}
```

Comment: It is said that your _versicherungsnehmerVC does not recognize setTag. As the object is not nil, verify first if [self loadViewController:@"2"] return an instance of VersicherungsnehmerVC

Comment: @HoaParis I added loadViewControllerByID method. Casting to BaseVC didn't help me.

Comment: No, you don't have to cast to BaseVC. I see that you cast to VersicherungsnehmerVC then call setTag. However, if return object is not a kind of VersicherungsnehmerVC, then you cannot call setTag on that casted object.

Comment: Verify if your ViewController (with identifier "2" normally) in storyboard uses VersicherungsnehmerVC as Class (in Custom Class section).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everithing looks just fine.

Try to clean project and build folder.

good luck ;)